# Start activity from view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view

I am new to Android programming, I am creating Introduction slides using View Pager and custom adaptor. I have two introduction slides and I want the third slide to be 'sign up' activity itself. With my current implementation, the third slide is just the layout of the activity and not the activity itself.

Can you suggest how to do so?

Here is my WelcomeActivity.java (I want to start LoginActivity.java)

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button next;
ViewPager vp;
LinearLayout layoutBars;
MyViewPAdaptor vpAdaptor;
TextView dots[];
int[] layouts;
PrefManager prfManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prfManager = new PrefManager(this);
    if (!prfManager.getIsFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    layoutBars = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    vpAdaptor = new MyViewPAdaptor();
    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.welcome_screen1,
            R.layout.welcome_screen2,
            R.layout.activity_login};
    vp.setAdapter(vpAdaptor);

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    // making notification bar transparent
    changeStatusBarColor();

    vp.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checking for last page
            // if last page home screen will be launched
            int current = getItem(+1);
            if (current < layouts.length-1) {
                // move to next screen
                vp.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                launchLoginScreen();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
    dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

    int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
    int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

    layoutBars.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(35);
        dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
        layoutBars.addView(dots[i]);
    }

    if (dots.length > 0)
        dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return vp.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    prfManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
private void launchLoginScreen() {
    prfManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
}

//  viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);

        // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
        if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
            // last page. make button text to GOT IT
            next.setText(getString(R.string.start));
        } else {
            // still pages are left
            next.setText(getString(R.string.next));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

/**
 * Making notification bar transparent
 */
private void changeStatusBarColor() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPAdaptor extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPAdaptor() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 2)
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: With this, the activity launches when we click on the layout (view). I want the activity to launch as soon as we scroll from the last welcome slide to the login layout

Comment: @JALAJGAMBHIR You mean when someone enters the third one they can go automatically to LoginActivity?

Comment: Yes. I want the login activity itself to be the third introduction slide

Comment: @JALAJGAMBHIR I edited my answer, hope it helps. but as a suggestion your logic for this is strange. Consider using fragments for modularity and content separation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And yes, in retrospect, this logic seems weird. I'll try to modify it using Fragments instead. Thanks for the suggestion!